# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json:

Tags: javascript, json, iframe

I run the following `javascript` code on [this page](http://www.roblox.com/catalog/json?browse.aspx?Subcategory=2&Keyword=&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=2&SortAggregation=0&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2) (In google Chrome) and recieve the following error in Console:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json:
```

Everything in my code works fine until it tries to refresh the iframe. That's when I recieve the message. I've shortened my code down quite a bit in order to view easier:

```
var filePath = document.URL;

var ifram = '<iframe id="frame" width="100%" height="1" scrolling="yes"></iframe>';
document.write(ifram);
var iframe = parent.document.getElementById("frame");
iframe.height = 600;
iframe.width = '60%';
iframe.src = filePath;

function search_prices(){
    var given_info = iframe.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML;
    var item_info = JSON.parse(given_info);
    setTimeout("iframe.src = filePath;", 500);
}

iframe.onload = search_prices;
```

I looked into similar questions about the same error but I wasnt able to find anything that helped me because i'm not in control of the server. The information on the page is what I have to work with.

Comment: I was able to get the code working just now. It refreshes and everything, but I still see the same error in Console every time it refreshes.

Comment: ...are you seriously loading that JSON string via an iframe?

Comment: The `src` of an iframe should be an HTML document, why are you trying to load JSON into an iframe?

Comment: Your site is full of MIME-type errors - you're also loading a lot of `text/html` and `text/plain` items into `<img>` elements it would appear. I'd really recommend reading up on what MIME-types and the `Content-type` header mean to a browser, and since you're using jQuery on the [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function.